# if else give false respond in elixir

Tags: elixir

i am new to elixir 
try to learn with basic 
but if else statement show some abnormal behavior

```
age = IO.gets ("age :  ") |> String.trim
        agea=Integer.parse(age)
        if agea > 10 do
            IO.puts "greater than 10 "
        else 
            IO.puts "les than 10 "
        end
```

set age as 5 using keyboard 
result is "greater than 10"

what is the issue 
how can i fixed it

and how do i perform
else if something like below code ( this below sample is not in elixir) 
eg:

```
a=5
if(a<3){
 printf("less than 3")
else if (a>=3 && a<10){
printf ("something ")
else{
 printf("something")
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Integer.parse/1` returns a tuple of integer and remaining string on success:

```
iex(1)> Integer.parse("123")
{123, ""}
```

and in Elixir, every tuple compares greater than every integer:

```
iex(2)> {} > 0
true
```

You're looking for `String.to_integer/1` if you want to convert a String to an Integer and raise an exception on invalid integers. The following should work:

```
age = IO.gets("age: ") |> String.trim
agea = String.to_integer(age)
...
```

Comment: its give this error 

** (ArgumentError) argument error
    :erlang.binary_to_integer("3\n")
    first.ex:59: X.ifelse/0

Comment: Are you sure you have `|> String.trim` in there? It should remove the trailing `\n`.

Comment: age = IO.gets ("age :  ") |> String.trim
  agea=String.to_integer(age)
  if agea > 10 do
   IO.puts "greater than 10 "
  else 
   IO.puts "les than 10 "
  end

Comment: Ah, try removing the space before the first `(` (copy from my answer). Otherwise you're just trimming the prompt text, not the return value.

Comment: not working age =IO.gets ("age :  ") |> String.trim
  agea =String.to_integer(age)
  if agea > 10 do
   IO.puts "greater than 10 "
  else 
   IO.puts "les than 10 "
  end

Comment: `age = IO.gets("age : ") |> String.trim`

Answer (score 1):

Answering the second question:

> how do i perform else if something like below code (this below sample is not in elixir) eg:
>
> ```
> a=5
> if(a<3){
>   printf("less than 3")
> else if (a>=3 && a<10){
>   printf ("something ")
> else{
>   printf("something")
> }
> ```

There are two ways:

**`case` with guards**

```
a = 5
IO.puts case a do
          a when (a < 3) -> "less than 3"
          a when (a >= 10) -> "greater than 10"
          else -> "something"
        end
```

**`cond`**

```
a = 5
IO.puts cond do
          a < 3 -> "less than 3"
          a >= 10 -> "greater than 10"
          true -> "something"
        end
```

`if` keyword is of very rare use in Elixir and is in general considered to be a code smell.